# Is it possible to tell sed to perform the subsequent subsitutions if the first one fails?

Tags: sed

I can pass a variable to sed substitution command as following:

```
$ myvar=helloworld
$ sed -r "s/$myvar/hellofoo/g; s/foo/bar/g" <(echo helloworld foo)
hellobar bar
```

But if the variable is empty, it fails:

```
$ myvar=
$ sed -r "s/$myvar/hellofoo/g; s/foo/bar/g" <(echo helloworld foo)
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

Is it possible to just skip the first substitution, and perform the second one? I'd like to have an output similar to this:

```
$ myvar=
$ sed -r "s/$myvar/hellofoo/g; s/foo/bar/g" <(echo helloworld foo)
helloworld bar
```

Comment: Note that the substitution fails if the variable contains a slash.

Comment: In GNU sed the `t` command is similar to the `b` command but only branches when the a substitution is successful. The `T` branches when a substitution is unsuccessful. The switch is reset following a branch from a `t` or `T` command.

Comment: @potong could you please cite some examples of `b`, `t` and `T` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `//` reuses the last regular expression, you can prepend your `sed` program with an innocuous command that uses a regex that won't ever match anything:

```
$ myvar=
$ sed -r "/$^/ =; s/$myvar/hellofoo/g; s/foo/bar/g" <(echo helloworld foo)
helloworld bar
```

Comment: Great to know what sed really meant with "no previous regular expression".

Comment: @lseki, If you want to read about it See section _[Regular expressions in sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)_. It is the third addition.

Answer (score 2):

You could switch to awk

```
awk -v var="$myvar" '(var!=""){gsub(var,"hellofoo")}{gsub("foo","bar")}1' <(echo helloworld foo)
```

Comment: conditionals are powerful indeed :-)